# Dense variables or sparse variables contribute more on random forest and svm?

Tags: r, data-visualization, random-forest, svm

I have a GC-MS data set containing 256 variables and 150 observations. Of these 256 variables, about 70 variables are very dense, and others are sparse. I performed a random forest and support vector machine-based recursive feature elimination with a caret package. Then, I found that the most important selected variables are dense; the sparse, biologically important ones seem skipped by `rf` and `svm`. Then I tried to replace all the 0 values with a super small value (Limit of detection), and it seemed better than before but was still dominant by dense variables.

So, I want to know if that means dense variables contribute more to the `rf` and `svm`? and how to solve the density-driving bias in the models.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are they sparse because they are missing?  Or do you mean they have few level contrasted against dense which has many distinct parameter values?

Answer (score 0):

Think about how a decision tree works (random forest).  Imagine you have a sparse variable in which only 10 out of 1000 observations have a value of 1 and the rest have 0.  Now lets say you have the beginning node with 1000 observations.  If you were to then split on this sparse variable, you could move at most 10 observations into a new node.  The other node would still contain (at least) 990 observations and look quite similar to the node with 1000 observations.  Thus this decrease in impurity this would cause (how importance is measured for random forests) would be quite small.

Comment: do you have some idea why support vector machine have the similar performance with rf ? SVM also tend to choose dense variables

Comment: Perhaps this qualifies as imbalanced dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a general property of sparse features, not just these models. A similar thing surprised me in my own research, when I had some features that were both very rare and very predictive compared to the others, and the math for my model showed the rare ones to be fairly worthless. For the rare occasions when you're classifying an instance that has that feature, the feature is amazing! But overall, on average across all features, it's not as helpful as those that are relevant for all instances.

I'd imagine this can be formalized in ways that would depend on the classifier's optimization function and/or loss function. But for hand-wavy intuition, I think it's similar to the [entropy of a Bernoulli variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_entropy_function), in which p = P(feature = 1) and [-log(p)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) = how strongly correlated the feature is with the class label. With sparse features, there's a small chance of a lot of info for classification, but overall a variable is more informative if it gives a small amount of information every time.